# Photo privacy - Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, privacy

I am trying to read the privacy settings of a Facebook photo posted by a user using my app.

On the [documentation for the privacy node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/privacy), it says photos return a field with the privacy information, but on the [documentation for the photo node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo), `privacy` isn't on the list of fields so when I try adding it to my list of fields, I get the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (privacy) on node type (Photo)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
$fbSession = new FacebookSession(ACCESS_TOKEN);

// Request photo info
$photoRequest = (new FacebookRequest(
    $fbSession,
    'GET',
    '/' . ID_PHOTO_FACEBOOK,
    ['fields' => 'from.name(1),link,source,likes.summary(1),comments.summary(1)']
))->execute();
$photoGraphObject = $photoRequest->getGraphObject();
```

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation say that you can set the privacy field when you update or create. It doesn't say there is a privacy field when you do a read

Comment: Yes I know, but is there a way to retrieve this information? Perhaps using another node?